# Symfony Security exception : $opsLimit must be 3 or greater

Tags: php, security, authentication, symfony4

My Symfony 4.4.9 app was working perfectly, I've made some simple fixes and rebuild the app (Docker), and I don't know why I can no more log in the admin panel :

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: 
"$opsLimit must be 3 or greater." 
at /app/vendor/symfony/security-core/Encoder/NativePasswordEncoder.php 
line 40 {
 "exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): 
 $opsLimit must be 3 or greater. 
 at /app/vendor/symfony/security-core/Encoder/NativePasswordEncoder.php:40)"
} []
```

I have no idea what does this mean ! I googled it but found nothing, however, in the dev environment every thing is ok

Any idea ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the error in my local dev environment. This is my security.yaml :

```
security:
  encoders:
    App\Entity\Utilisateur:
        algorithm: argon2i
        memory_cost: 16384
        time_cost: 2
        threads: 4
```

I've changed **time_cost** to **3** and now it's ok :)

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking at line 40 at /app/vendor/symfony/security-core/Encoder/NativePasswordEncoder.php. Log the whole stack trace and you will see what the error is. This is the actual file

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Symfony package.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException;

/**
 * Hashes passwords using password_hash().
 *
 * @author Elnur Abdurrakhimov <elnur@elnur.pro>
 * @author Terje Bråten <terje@braten.be>
 * @author Nicolas Grekas <p@tchwork.com>
 */
final class NativePasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoderInterface, SelfSaltingEncoderInterface
{
    private const MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 4096;

    private $algo = PASSWORD_BCRYPT;
    private $options;

    /**
     * @param string|null $algo An algorithm supported by password_hash() or null to use the stronger available algorithm
     */
    public function __construct(int $opsLimit = null, int $memLimit = null, int $cost = null, string $algo = null)
    {
        $cost = $cost ?? 13;
        $opsLimit = $opsLimit ?? max(4, \defined('SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE') ? SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE : 4);
        $memLimit = $memLimit ?? max(64 * 1024 * 1024, \defined('SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE') ? SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE : 64 * 1024 * 1024);

        if (3 > $opsLimit) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('$opsLimit must be 3 or greater.');
        }

        if (10 * 1024 > $memLimit) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('$memLimit must be 10k or greater.');
        }

        if ($cost < 4 || 31 < $cost) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('$cost must be in the range of 4-31.');
        }

        $algos = [1 => PASSWORD_BCRYPT, '2y' => PASSWORD_BCRYPT];

        if (\defined('PASSWORD_ARGON2I')) {
            $this->algo = $algos[2] = $algos['argon2i'] = (string) PASSWORD_ARGON2I;
        }

        if (\defined('PASSWORD_ARGON2ID')) {
            $this->algo = $algos[3] = $algos['argon2id'] = (string) PASSWORD_ARGON2ID;
        }

        if (null !== $algo) {
            $this->algo = $algos[$algo] ?? $algo;
        }

        $this->options = [
            'cost' => $cost,
            'time_cost' => $opsLimit,
            'memory_cost' => $memLimit >> 10,
            'threads' => 1,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function encodePassword(string $raw, ?string $salt): string
    {
        if (\strlen($raw) > self::MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH || ((string) PASSWORD_BCRYPT === $this->algo && 72 < \strlen($raw))) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException('Invalid password.');
        }

        // Ignore $salt, the auto-generated one is always the best

        return password_hash($raw, $this->algo, $this->options);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isPasswordValid(string $encoded, string $raw, ?string $salt): bool
    {
        if ('' === $raw) {
            return false;
        }

        if (\strlen($raw) > self::MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH) {
            return false;
        }

        if (0 !== strpos($encoded, '$argon')) {
            // BCrypt encodes only the first 72 chars
            return (72 >= \strlen($raw) || 0 !== strpos($encoded, '$2')) && password_verify($raw, $encoded);
        }

        if (\extension_loaded('sodium') && version_compare(SODIUM_LIBRARY_VERSION, '1.0.14', '>=')) {
            return sodium_crypto_pwhash_str_verify($encoded, $raw);
        }

        if (\extension_loaded('libsodium') && version_compare(phpversion('libsodium'), '1.0.14', '>=')) {
            return \Sodium\crypto_pwhash_str_verify($encoded, $raw);
        }

        return password_verify($raw, $encoded);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function needsRehash(string $encoded): bool
    {
        return password_needs_rehash($encoded, $this->algo, $this->options);
    }
}
```

This is the relevant part of it:

```
    $opsLimit = $opsLimit ?? max(4, \defined('SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE') ? SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE : 4);
    $memLimit = $memLimit ?? max(64 * 1024 * 1024, \defined('SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE') ? SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE : 64 * 1024 * 1024);

    if (3 > $opsLimit) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('$opsLimit must be 3 or greater.');
    }
```

Basically you have `SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE` defined and is lower or equal to three. Search for all occurrences of this text in your files and find the culprit.

Comment: the algorithm parameter was ``argon2i``, when the problem happened i changed it to ``auto``, and as you said the message error was linked to ``sodium`` algo ! I went back to ``argon2i`` and now it's ok, but I don't have any idea what was wrong :( It's really frustrating when you a problem is fiexed without knowing what happened !

Comment: @Sami it's quite possible that something is automatically issuing these changes. I believe that my answer offers a solution to this problem, even though, changing the algorithm is also a possible solution.